# Call Async task repeatedly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android app and I want to call an AsyncTask when a specific page is loaded. I need the AsyncTask to be called over and over again. I am new to android development, let me know if I missed anything in the explanation.

Comment: I think you should look up services in the Android documentation. You can let something run over and over with it. Let me know if it worked ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interfaces to solve this.

Interface file LoadingResultInterface.java:

```
public interface LoadingResultInterface {
    void onLoadingResult(int errorCode);
}
```

Activity code:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoadingResultInterface {

    @Override
    public void onLoadingResult(int errorCode) {
        if (errorCode != xxxxx)
            new SomeLoader(this).execute();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask Code:

```
private class SomeLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    private Activity activity;
    LoadingResultInterface loadingListener;

    public SomeLoader(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        loadingListener = (LoadingResultInterface)activity;
    }

    protected final Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // int result = someJob();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        loadingListener.onLoadingResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good thing to let something "run over and over again" - you probably implement some kind of polling, which you shouldn't do on a mobile device for a myriad of reasons (most important ones being battery life and overly heavy data transfer over mobile networks).

So try to evaluate your business criteria, think of caching or "how often do I need new data?" and also if implementing cloud-to-device messaging could be an answer of your polling needs.

Comment: Its about updating the coordinates of an object in movement. It is not heavy data transfer, just a string.